# How to use Next.js getStaticProps while in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, docker-compose, containers

I'm building an app that uses Next.js with it's api routes capability and getStaticProps functionality. I want to ship it, full stack, using docker-compose. However, the webapp container fails on build every time, because it can't connect to the database container to get it's props on build time. I tried wait-for-it.sh , depends_on, healthcheck, waiting script in the Dockerfile, I even tried splitting components into different yaml files. All with no result.

I want the compose file/files to:

1. start and populate mongodb frim mongo-init.js (works)
2. wait for the mongo container to be fully operational and then begin the build process of nextjs container.

Is it even possible to make this config work? **Is there a way to start building the container image only after the first one is up and running?**

Current Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Current docker-compose.yml (with a lot of trial and error in it):

```
version: "2.4"

services:  
  baza:
    container_name: baza
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: <secret_login>
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: <secret_password>
        MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ITM
    ports:
        - 27017:27017
    volumes:
        - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
        - ./MongoITM:/data/db
    networks:
        - siec-kontenerow-ITM

  strona:
    container_name: strona
    restart: always
    # volumes:
    #   - ./:/usr/src/app
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
    networks:
      - siec-kontenerow-ITM
     # - nextjs
    # healthcheck:
    #   test: curl --fail http://baza:27017 || exit 1
    #   interval: 30s
    #   timeout: 10s
    #   retries: 5
    # depends_on:
    #   - baza
    
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    
    # command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "baza:27017", "--", "npm", "start"]
        
    

networks:
  siec-kontenerow-ITM: 
    driver: bridge
```

Fragment of error code which occurs while building Dockerfile for webapp container:

```
/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:278
51.09                 const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
51.09                                      ^
51.09 
51.09 MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out
51.09     at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:278:38)
51.09     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
51.09     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
51.09   reason: TopologyDescription {
51.09     type: 'Unknown',
51.09     servers: Map(1) {
51.09       'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
```

Any help appreciated. Cheers,
Maciej

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)

Comment: @Pino It doesn't. OP needs the database at build time. Not at run time. Compose won't bring the database up at build time, no matter how long you wait.

Comment: @hans-kilian  The title refers to docker-compose.  I think OP says "building the container" instead of "starting the container".

Comment: An image build can never talk to another container, for a couple of mechanical reasons.  Having your application build depend on the database seems a little odd (what happens if the database changes but you don't rebuild?).  Maybe you can generate whichever file ahead-of-time, on the host, before you `docker build` the image?

Comment: @DavidMaze It seems odd at first, but it's a powerful feature of nextjs that lets you generate static web pages based on data sources like databases. But to generate the static pages, it needs access to the database at build time. And compose can't do that. https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. @hans-kilian is right, I tried to use that feature and I found a workaround. I removed npm run build from my dockerfile and instaead put it into a sh file that runs on every container start. Since next needs to build static assets from db every time anyway, I thought it would do the job and it did. I could post those files if anyone is interested. Cheers, M

Comment: Great that you got it to work. Another solution would be to spin up the database and do the build outside of Docker Compose using just Docker. If your site is 100% static, you could then use something like Nginx to serve it, rather than Node.